# Determining total of primitive operations and running time for code

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, time-complexity

i needed some help with these problem in DSA

For the given pseudo code:

```
for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) a[i] = 0; 
for( i=0; i<n; i++ )
  for( j=0; j<n; j++ ) 
    a[i] += a[j] + i + j;
```

Determine:

```
1. Total number of primitive operations
2. Running Time
```

Comment: What is [DSA](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/DSA)?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you and future readers understand the concepts. It is expected of you to show your partial progress, thoughts or where you got stuck. This site is a question-and-answer place instead of a solution rendering service.  Have you read the answers to [_how to ask a good homework question_](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284)?